# Using video to prove an alarm is flashing

Tags: framerate

I'm in a bit of an annoying problem. I know nothing about video, so sorry if I'm using wrong terminology.

I live in an apartment buliding in downtown Tel Aviv. On the ground floor of my building there's a sunglasses shop. Recently, its alarm has been going on at night, keeping me up with its incessant siren.

When it happened, I got out of bed, got dressed, and discovered the source of the alarm. I took a video of it with my Pixel 6 camera, and by "it" I mean the sunglasses store, the siren sound, and the light flashing on the alarm device that's on the outside of the store.

Today I talked about it with the manager of the alarm store. He claims that the alarm isn't his. I was going to use my damning video as proof that the alarm is indeed his. However, when I watched the video, the light didn't flash.

I suspect that because the light flashes for such a short time, it clashes with the Pixel 6's video camera framerate, making the light invisible.

In case this dispute with the store owner escalates, I want to have definite proof that his alarm's light is flashing in my videos, otherwise he might be able to claim the alarm isn't his, and I won't be able to sleep at night.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: I see now that the Pixel 6's settings have an option for 60 FPS framerate. I'll try that next time and see whether it works.